# Read integer after reading a string from a file using fscanf

Tags: c, string, format, scanf, format-specifiers

I've made a program which has test.txt file which contains following

> 24 Rohit Soni 1997

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *f;
    int no,i;
    char *name;
    f=fopen("test.txt","r");
    fscanf(f,"%d %[^[0-9]]s %d ",&no, name, &i);
    printf("%d %s %d",no, name,i);
    fclose(f);
}
```

But it is not showing the correct output.
Output is:

> 24 Rohit Soni 12804

Please tell me what to do.  Why is it not accepting an integer after taking string from `fscanf` using `%[` format specifier.

Comment: Don't leave a trailing space in the format string if you might use it interactively (with you typing at the keyboard).

Comment: Rule 1 about f/scanf: always check the return value. Rule 2 about f/scanf: don't try to use them for anything complicated.  Rule 3 about f/scanf: as soon as you're comfortable enough with C to do so, learn how to read lines using `fgets`, and parse lines into tokens some other way, so that you will never have to use f/scanf again, because: Rule 4 about f/scanf: they're really not good for much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test the return code from `fscanf()`; it would tell you 2 values are converted instead of the 3 you expected.  You should always test the return code from `fscanf()`, usually for the expected number of conversions and only very seldom will you test for EOF or 0.

The problem is that a scan set `%[^…]` is not a modifier for `%s`, and also the scan set stops at the first `]` unless that immediately follows the `[` for a regular scan set or `[^` for a negated scan set.  So, your format string is looking for a sequence of 'not a digit nor an `[`' characters, followed by a `]` and an `s` — and it isn't finding the `]` and `s` in the input.

You need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open '%s' for reading\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    int no,i;
    char name[128];

    if (fscanf(f, "%d %127[^0-9] %d", &no, name, &i) != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read three values\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d [%s] %d\n", no, name, i);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

You need to check that `fopen()` worked.  The error message should include the file name that you failed to open.  (If you paid attention to command line arguments — using `int main(int argc, char **argv)` — you would report the program name from `argv[0]` in the error messages too.)  You need to allocate space for `name` rather than use an uninitialized pointer.  The [correct return type for `main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) is `int` — though Microsoft does allow `void`.  Note that the input format ensures there is no [buffer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c).

I've enclosed the name in `[…]` in the output so you can see that the name includes the trailing space.  The output I get is:

```
24 [Rohit Soni ] 1997
```

Comment: `if (f == 0)`, wow, I didn't know you could do that. Cool, nice answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan , But I'm having a little doubt regarding %127[^0-9]   why you have written 127 here and didn't even wrote 's' (as we are accepting a string)?

Comment: See the link under 'buffer overflow' for why 127 is appropriate. As I said in the answer, `%[…]` is a conversion specifier on its own; it is not a modifier for `%s`.